# How to find invalid hours

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to built a query in Oracle SQL Developer that would return hours that are not inside business hours (08:00 am-5:00PM) in order to clean it.
The column is named auction_time. The problem is that the table contains 2 million rows and al type of formats such as '9:45 am', '9 am', '11:00:00', '23:00' and a few more.
I have tried smthing like but it returns other type of results as well
select * from all_foreclosures where   auction_time between '17%' and '24%';
Can you help?

Comment: What is the layout of the field? nvarchar, datetime, varchar, ...?

Comment: VARCHAR2(16 BYTE)

Comment: Unfortunately this sounds like something that is nearly impossible to do since there is no straightforward format is used on the column itself.

Comment: Perform a `SELECT DISTINCT auction_time FROM all_foreclosures` and let's see what we can do from there. There might be a way to convert all those to a standard DATETIME format and then have them filtered.

Comment: ...and another proof why you should **never** store times or dates as strings!

Comment: 665 distinct auction_time

Comment: .
00:00:00
00:00:08
00:00:11
00:11:00
00:15:00
00:30:00
00:40:00
00:45:00
01:00
01:00 AM
01:00 pm
01:00:00
01:05 PM
01:05:00
01:10 PM
01:10:00
01:15:00
01:20:00
01:25:00
01:30
01:30 pm
01:30:00
01:30PM
01:35:00
01:36 PM
01:40:00
01:43 PM
01:45:00
01:50:00
01:55:00
02/09/2006
02:00
02:00 PM
02:00:00
02:00PM
02:15:00
02:20:00
02:30 pm
02:30:00
03/30/2006
03:00 PM
03:00:00
03:03 PM
03:05 PM
03:15:00
03:30:00
04:00:00
04:30 PM
04:40:00
04:45:00
05:00:00
06:17 PM
06:30:00
07:30:00
08:00:00
08:01 PM
08:15:00
08:30 AM
08:30:00

Comment: 08:45:00
08:55:00
08:59:00
09-08-2004
09:00
09:00 a.m.
09:00 am
09:00 PM
09:00:00
09:00:00 AM
09:05:00
09:10 AM
09:10:00
09:15:00
09:20 AM
09:20:00
09:25:00
09:30
09:30 am
09:30:00
09:30AM
09:35:00
09:36:00
09:40:00
09:45 AM
09:45:00
09:50:00
09:55:00
1 pm
1);00
1.00 pm
1.00PM
1.30PM
1/10/1900  12:00
10
10 am
10.00 am
10.00AM
10.00PM
10.30 am
10.30AM
1015
1045
10: 00 am
10: am
10:)0
10:0 am
10:00
10:00 a.m
10:00 a.m 
10:00 a.m.
10:00 am
10:00 AM 
10:00 am  
10:00 pm
10:00,1400 FIFTH
10:000
10:000 am
10:00:00
10:00:00AM

Comment: 10:00am
10:00AM 
10:00AM0
10:00AM2
10:00M 
10:00PM
10:00PM 
10:02:00
10:03 AM
10:03:00
10:03AM 
10:04:00
10:05
10:05 AM
10:05:00
10:06:00
10:08:00
10:090 am
10:09:00
10:0AM
10:10 a.m
10:10 AM
10:10:00
10:10AM 
10:12:00
10:14:00
10:15
10:15 am
10:15:00
10:15am
10:15AM 
10:17:00
10:18:00
10:20:00
10:20AM 
10:21:00
10:23:00
10:24:00
10:25:00
10:25AM 
10:27:00
10:29:00
10:30
10:30 am
10:30:00
10:30am
10:30AM 
10:30M 
10:30PM
10:30PM 
10:32:00
10:33:00
10:33AM 
10:34:00
10:34AM 
10:35:00
10:36:00
10:37:00
10:38:00
10:39:00

Comment: 10:39AM 
10:40:00
10:42:00
10:43:00
10:44:00
10:45
10:45 am
10:45:00
10:45am
10:45AM 
10:46:00
10:47:00
10:48:00
10:50:00
10:51:00
10:52:00
10:53:00
10:54:00
10:56:00
10:57:00
10:58:00
10:OOAM
10;00
10;00 AM
10;:00
11 am
11.00 am
11.00AM
110:00AM
11: 00 am
11: am
11:0 am
11:0-0 am
11:00
11:00 
11:00  AM
11:00 a.m
11:00 a.m.
11:00 am
11:00 am 
11:00 pm
11:000 am
11:009A
11:00:00
11:00A
11:00a,
11:00am
11:00AM 
11:00M 
11:00PM
11:00PM 
11:02:00
11:03:00
11:03AM 
11:04:00
11:05:00
11:06:00
11:08:00
11:09:00
11:0am

Comment: 11:10 AM
11:10:00
11:11AM 
11:12:00
11:14:00
11:15
11:15 am
11:15:00
11:15AM
11:15AM 
11:16:00
11:18:00
11:20 am
11:20:00
11:20am
11:21:00
11:22:00
11:23:00
11:24:00
11:25:00
11:26:00
11:27:00
11:30
11:30 A.M.
11:30 am
11:30 am 
11:30 amj
11:30 sm
11:30:00
11:30am
11:30AM 
11:30M 
11:30PM
11:30PM 
11:32:00
11:33:00
11:33AM 
11:34:00
11:35:00
11:36:00
11:38:00
11:39:00
11:39AM 
11:40:00
11:42:00
11:44:00
11:45 am
11:45:00
11:45AM
11:45AM 
11:47:00
11:48:00
11:49:00
11:50:00
11:51:00
11:53:00
11:54:00
11:55:00
11:56:00
11:57:00

Comment: 11:58:00
11:59:00
11;00 am
11;00AM
11;15 am
11A.M.
12 :00 PM
12 noon
12 p.m
12 p.m.
12 pm
12-15PM
12.00 noon
12.00 p.m
12.00 p.m.
12.00PM
12.15PM
12/06/2005
12/8/2006
1219
1223
12: noon
12:00
12:00 A.M.
12:00 noon
12:00 p.m
12:00 p.m 
12:00 p.m.
12:00 p.nm
12:00 pm
12:00:00
12:00:00PM
12:00AM
12:00AM 
12:00M 
12:00Noon
12:00pm
12:00PM 
12:01:00
12:02:00
12:03:00
12:04:00
12:05:00
12:05PM
12:06:00
12:10 PM
12:10:00
12:12 PM
12:12:00
12:15 pm
12:15:00
12:15am
12:15pm
12:15PM 
12:18:00
12:20:00
12:22:00
12:24:00
12:26:00
12:29 PM

Comment: 12:30 am
12:30 pm
12:30:00
12:30:00PM
12:30am
12:30pm
12:30PM 
12:35:00
12:40:00
12:45 pm
12:45:00
12:45pm
12:50:00
12:55:00
12::30
12:l5 PM
12:noon
12;00 p.m
12;15PM
12;30
12;30 PM
12noon
1300
1301
13:00
13:00:00
13:05:00
13:10:00
13:15:00
13:20:00
13:25:00
13:30:00
13:35:00
13:40:00
13:45:00
13:50:00
13:55:00
145
14:00
14:00:00
14:05:00
14:06:00
14:10:00
14:15
14:15:00
14:20:00
14:25:00
14:30
14:30:00
14:35:00
14:40:00
14:45:00
14:50:00
14:55:00
15:00:00
15:01:00
15:02:00
15:03:00
15:04:00
15:05:00

Comment: 15:06:00
15:07:00
15:10:00
15:15:00
15:30:00
15:45:00
16:00:00
16:15:00
16:30:00
16:45:00
17455
17:00:00
17:30:00
17:40:00
18:00:00
18:15:00
18:30:00
18:45:00
19:00:00
1: 00 pm
1:00
1:00 p.m
1:00 p.m.
1:00 pm
1:00'
1:00:00PM
1:00AM
1:00AM 
1:00M 
1:00p.m
1:00pm
1:00PM 
1:00PM1
1:00PM2
1:03M 
1:03pm
1:15
1:15 pm
1:15PM
1:30
1:30 am
1:30 p.m
1:30 p.m.
1:30 pm
1:30AM
1:30AM 
1:30M 
1:30pm
1:30PM 
1:30PM0
1:30PM1
1:30PM7
1:3OPM
1:45 am
1:45 pm
1:45PM
1;00
2 p.m
2 pm
2.00 p.m.

Comment: 2.00 pm
2.00PM
2.30PM
20:00 pm
20:00AM
20:30:00
2128
21:00:00
21:30:00
21:30P
21:45:00
22:00:00
22:15:00
22:30:00
22:45:00
23
230
2300
234235
23:00:00
23:30:00
25541
25:00:00
25:15:00
26:30:00
299468
2: pm
2:0 p.m.
2:0 pm
2:00
2:00  p.m.
2:00 am
2:00 p.m
2:00 p.m.
2:00 pm
2:00 pm 
2:00 pmq
2:00:00PM
2:00A
2:00AM
2:00p.m.
2:00pm
2:00PM 
2:00PM0
2:00PM4
2:15
2:15 pm
2:15am
2:15PM
2:20PM
2:3 pm
2:30
2:30 am
2:30 pm
2:300PM
2:30AM
2:30pm
2:30PM 
2:35 PM
2:45 pm

Comment: 2;00 p.m
2;00 p.m.
2;00 pm
2;30 PM
3 pm
3.00PM
31810
31:30PM
325793
3: 00 pm
3:0 pm
3:00
3:00  pm
3:00 p.m
3:00 pm
3:00 pm 
3:00 pma
3:00:00PM
3:00am
3:00pm
3:00PM 
3:0OPM
3:15pm
3:30 am
3:30 pm
3:30AM
3:30pm
3;00 pm
3;00pm
4/2/2004
400
46:08:00
46:88:00
4:00 pm
4:00PM
4:30 pm
4:30PM 
5:00pm
5:00PM 
5:30 am
6:30 pm
7295
7:00 pm
7:00pm
819
8:00am
8:00AM 
8:00PM 
8:30 AM
8:30am
8:45 am
8:45am
9
9 am
9+
9.00 AM
9.00AM
9.15 am
9.15AM
9.30 am

Comment: 9.30AM
9000
90:00AM
930 am
9300
930am
9360
945
9630
9: 00 am
9:0 am
9:0-0 am
9:00
9:00 a,
9:00 a.m
9:00 A.M.
9:00 am
9:00 am 
9:00 M
9:00 pm
9:00:00AM
9:00am
9:00AM 
9:00AMAM
9:00PM
9:00PM 
9:10 am
9:15
9:15 am
9:15 pm
9:15am
9:15AM 
9:20AM
9:3 am
9:30
9:30  am
9:30 a.m
9:30 am
9:30 am`
9:30 zm
9:30'
9:30A
9:30am
9:30AM 
9:30AM0
9:30AM1
9:30pm
9:330 am
9:330AM
9:35
9:3am
9:40
9:40 am
9:45
9:45 am
9:45am
9:O0AM
9;30AM
9;AM
:00 am
n/a
noon
test

Comment: Please post a reduced set of data, as formatted text, by editing the question instead of adding comments.

Comment: The first thing I would do is identifying all the possible formats; once given this, it would be easier to understand how to convert each value and then perform the needed check. Can you list the possible formats of your data?

Comment: Do **not** post code or additional information in comments. **[edit]** your question and add sample data as [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `CASE` statement and multiple regular expressions to match different formats (you will need to identify all the different formats):

```
SELECT *
FROM   (
  SELECT t.*,
       ( CASE
           WHEN REGEXP_LIKE( auction_time, '^\s*(0?[1-9]|1[0-2])\s*[ap]m\s*$', 'i' )
           THEN TO_DATE( auction_time, 'HH12AM' )
           WHEN REGEXP_LIKE( auction_time, '^\s*(0?[1-9]|1[0-2]):[0-5]?\d\s*[ap]m\s*$','i')
           THEN TO_DATE( auction_time, 'HH12:MIAM' )
           WHEN REGEXP_LIKE( auction_time, '^\s*([01]?\d|2[0-3]):[0-5]?\d\s*$' )
           THEN TO_DATE( auction_time, 'HH24:MI' )
           WHEN REGEXP_LIKE( auction_time, '^\s*([01]?\d|2[0-3]):[0-5]?\d:[0-5]?\d\s*$' )
           THEN TO_DATE( auction_time, 'HH24:MI:SS' )
         END
       - TRUNC( SYSDATE, 'Y' )
       ) * 24 AS Hours
  FROM   your_table t
)
WHERE hours < 8 OR hours > 17
```