# Convert Oracle VARCHAR2 to DATE and exclude invalid data

Tags: sql, oracle, date

I have column `column_name VARCHAR2` with various data. To convert it to `DATE` datatype I wrote following expression:

```
SELECT TO_DATE(column_name, 'YYYY/MM/DD') FROM schema.table;
```

But it gives me error:

> ORA-01841: (full) year must be between -4713 and +9999, and not be 0
>   01841. 00000 -  "(full) year must be between -4713 and +9999, and not be 0"
>
> *Cause:    Illegal year entered
>
> *Action:   Input year in the specified range

Column consist of `NULL`, `space`, `00000000` and string dates like "`20161111`".

To exclude invalid data I decided to use `DECODE`:

```
SELECT DECODE(column_name, 
              '', NULL, 
              '00000000', NULL, 
              TO_DATE(column_name, 'YYYY/MM/DD')) 
FROM schema.table;
```

But in this case I get a following error:

> ORA-01841: (full) year must be between -4713 and +9999, and not be 0
>   01841. 00000 -  "(full) year must be between -4713 and +9999, and not be 0"
>
> *Cause:    Illegal year entered
>
> *Action:   Input year in the specified range

Data example:

```
| # | column_name |
|---|-------------|
| 1 | 00000000    |
| 2 |             |
| 3 | (null)      |
| 4 | 20161111    |
```

What am I doing wrong?

Is there any solution to exclude all invalid data without including it in cases of DECODE?

Comment: can you show some sample data from the column?

Comment: Please don't paste pictures, use text.

Comment: Do you consider `20161111` as valid? (i.e. 2016-11-11)

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit yes

Comment: Then you must not use `'YYYY/MM/DD'` as pattern. Does the column have any values in this format, i.e. `2016/11/11`

Comment: Ah the bane of allowing bad data into a system.  Sanitize inputs and this problem doesn't exist.  Use the correct datatype for the correct data and this problem ceases to exist.  The pain you have is because proper work wasn't done up front.

Comment: Date format you are using is incorrent - you should use YYYYMMDD.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could write a function like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION VARCHAR_TO_DATE(str IN VARCHAR2) RETURN DATE AS
BEGIN
   RETURN TO_DATE(str, 'YYYY/MM/DD');
EXCEPTION
   WHEN OTHERS THEN
      RETURN NULL;
END;
```

Then use it as

```
SELECT varchar_to_date(column_name) FROM schema.table;
```

Any invalid strings will result in a NULL value.

Comment: Good answer - any other approach would necessarily duplicate at least part of the Oracle date validation

Answer (score 1):

Write a [user-defined function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37660175/1509264) that will handle the exceptions:

```
CREATE FUNCTION parse_Date(
  in_string     VARCHAR2,
  in_format     VARCHAR2 DEFAULT 'YYYY/MM/DD',
  in_nls_params VARCHAR2 DEFAULT NULL
) RETURN DATE DETERMINISTIC
AS
BEGIN
  RETURN TO_DATE( in_string, in_format, in_nls_params );
EXCEPTION
  WHEN OTHERS THEN
    RETURN NULL;
END;
/
```

Then you can do:

```
SELECT parse_Date( column_name, 'YYYY/MM/DD' )
FROM   schema.table
```

Otherwise you could use [regular expressions to match different valid date patterns](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41933933/1509264).

Answer (score 1):

You can just use `CASE` and `REGEXP_LIKE()`:

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN REGEXP_LIKE(column_name, '^[12][0-9]{3}/[01][0-9]/[0123][0-9]$')
             THEN TO_DATE(column_name, 'YYYY/MM/DD')
        END)
```

Obviously, this is not a perfect solution, but it works under many circumstances.